# Where's the rails release notes or changelog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doc

Rails 3.0.4 just released.
But I don't see any changelog documents.

So where is the rails 3.0.4 changelog? 
I need to know if I should upgrade all my apps to 3.0.4 from 3.0.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [blog post](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails) and you can read the single CHANGELOG files

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/actionmailer/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/actionpack/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/activemodel/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/activerecord/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/activeresource/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/activesupport/CHANGELOG
- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-0-4-security/railties/CHANGELOG

You can also compare the changes between 3.0.3 and 3.0.4

- https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.0.3...v3.0.4

Answer (score 5):

Simone's answer has inspired me to collect links to all the changelogs on one page. Includes versions 3.2, 3.1, 3.0, 2.3 as well as the upcoming 4.0.

http://jonathanjulian.com/2013/01/the-rails-changelogs/

I'll try to keep that post up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

This [weblog](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) has links to the changelog of each component as well as the commits for each version.